# Lynx request to Google search doesn't work

Tags: linux, centos, search-engine, lynx

I have Centos 6.2 x64, Lynx 2.8.6rel.5 on vps.

I try in console

```
[root@turbomoney ~]# lynx http://www.google.com/search?complete=0&num=100&hl=en&complete=0&site=webhp&source=hp&q=Hello%20World&start=0
[9] 14223
[10] 14224
[11] 14225
[12] 14226
[13] 14227
[14] 14228
[15] 14229
[10]   Done                    num=100
[11]   Done                    hl=en
[12]   Done                    complete=0
[13]   Done                    site=webhp
[14]   Done                    source=hp
[root@turbomoney ~]#
```

This request works in my browser, but Lynx doesn't understant it. 
What's wrong? How to make request to google with 100 result per page through Lynx?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try quote your link with " :

```
lynx "http://www.google.com/search?complete=0&num=100&hl=en&complete=0&site=webhp&source=hp&q=Hello%20World&start=0"
```